Golden Spiral How to plot trajectory of a point on a circle?
I have a simple question.  Have searched everywhere on the net and cant seem to find anything that answers this.  See the attached image.  The image describes how the horizontal line ( diameter ) is being multiplied by powers of phi, so we see a width of the spiral grow from a unit measure of 1 to 1.618, 2.618, etc...  What I want to know however is if we have a particle situated at 45 degrees when the spiral diameter is at the default size of "1", then as the diameter grows by powers of phi then the degree position of the particle should change to something other than 45 degrees.  How do I determine what the new degree position of the particle is as the diameter grows?  Ive been studying a number of different formulas for spirals ; golden, fibo, logarithmic, etc but I cant find much out there for tracking the position of particles on spirals.  What Im really hoping for though is a math solution for tracking a particles movement on a golden spiral.  Thanks for any feedback you can provide.

My current understanding is that for a golden spiral every time the diameter grows there is a quarter turn of 90 degrees, so my initial thought is that if I want to track the new degree position of the particle I should simply add 90 degrees to it for each turn, so that if the particle position is originally at 45 degrees then one turn would simply be 45 + 90 degrees = 135 degrees.
So if I do one turn then the starting point of 45 becomes 135 degrees after growing the diameter by phi.
Does this sound right?  Am I on the right track?
See this image for more clarification of what I mean ;


See solution in the answer here.

A logarithmic spiral is defined as
$$z=e^{(b+i)\theta}$$
where $b$ is the flair coefficient
$$
b=\frac{\ln q}{\Delta \theta}
$$
and $q$ is the growth rate per $\Delta\theta$ change in the angle. Thus if we allow that $\theta=n\Delta\theta$, then the radius is given by
$$
r=e^{bn\Delta\theta}=e^{\frac{\ln q}{\Delta \theta}n\Delta\theta}=q^n
$$
In the case of golden spiral, $q=\varphi$ and $\Delta\theta=\pi/2$, hence the radius increases as $\varphi$ for every rotation of $\pi/2$.

Hi Clyde, thanks for your response - Im not looking for how to return the radius increase value though, what Im trying to find out is how a particle situated at a certain position on the initial arm of the spiral would change position on the second arm after the radius has grown by a rotation of phi.  So if on the first arm the particle is at 45 degrees, then after the first phi rotation has it moved to 45 + 90 degrees?

Also, as I review your formula for radius, what does the " i " represent in the statement z=e^(b+i)θ  ?   If I understand correctly you are saying the proper equation for a logarithmic golden spiral is ; e^(ln(Phi)/(pi/2)) ?

This is the complex notation. Euler's formula tells us that $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. The 'polar' form of a complex number is $z=re^{i\theta}$. $i= \sqrt{-1}$ is the so-called imaginary number. So, yes, the equation you wrote just above is the radius of the golden spiral.

Thanks Clyde, so in the equation ;  " e^(ln(Phi)/(pi/2)) " I do not have to include  i " the imaginary number then?  Also, how can I track the particle movement on the spiral arm with this?  Do I just move the particle by 90 degrees for each turn?

I think that's correct. In Cartesian coordinates, $x=r\cos\theta,\ y=r\sin\theta$, where $r=e^{2\ln(\varphi)\theta/\pi}=\varphi^{2\theta/\pi}$
